# Absolute positioned div in a fixed wrapper

Tags: css

I reproduced the exact context of my problem:
on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/karwG) and on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ffBF/14/).

It seems to work as I expected but when I'm applying the same styles to the almost the same DOM (there are some other elements but those are not positioned and should not affect the end result) I've got the following problem:

[image: In firefox]

[image: with firebug]

As you can see. The red box is somehow under the top div even if that one is positioned static. What am I missing? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I'm trying to obtain the effect shown in CodePen or jsFiddle. However in my browser the absolute box does not go over the fixed div. When checked with firebug (second image with that blue hovering square shown) the absolute box is there.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Could you be clearer?  Is the image what you want to see?

Comment: What browser are you on?

Comment: @SimonAronsson Tried it on Latest Mozilla Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for, or am I misunderstanding your question?

http://codepen.io/simonaronsson/pen/eiAJd

However, from what I can tell - the whole code is a bit messy. You've got a container on 30px but the box is 200x200? Also: Why are you fixing the container and box to the bottom if you want them to be at the top? It is very hard to understand what you're getting at. You probably need to write a better description of what you actually want.

Or maybe this was what you had in mind?

http://codepen.io/simonaronsson/pen/vxuwd

Actually, I'm a bit lost. I'll try to rewrite my answer when you've elaborated a bit. :)